# i'm creating asp.net page with login and signup. my page will work with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localhost

I want to make a ecommerce project. my login and sign page working well but my session state is not working. Please help me.
**This is my page code.**

```
string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["email_id"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

This my login button codding.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str1);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sign_up where email_id='" + TextBox2.Text + "' and pwd ='" + TextBox3.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if(dr.HasRows)
            {
                Session["email_id"] = dr.GetString(2);
                Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u tell me what is the error message or what the current behavior

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure your browser accept and store cookies.
2. Be sure server date and time and client date and time are correct.
3. Be sure session is enable. (SessionState tag in web.config)
4. Be sure Session["email_id"] has correct value after set it. (In debug mode)

Comment: you chceked my code. it is right or any mistake is there.

Comment: Mistake? mmm, I don't think.
Please check number 4, Add breakpoint in Response.Redirect line and check that session has correct value.